# How to use different Chrome devtools protocol version

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I want to use some of the experimental features of Chrome DevTools protocol such as [DOMSnapshot.getSnapshot](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOMSnapshot#method-getSnapshot).

Right now no matter how I open chrome in the remote mode it always opens in `Protocol-Version: 1.3`

I have tried chrome-dev chrome-canary. Even Microsoft edge dev version but none is working.

I have tried checking if there are any chrome flags or command-line arguments or dev tools protocol commands to switch the Protocol version. But none is working.

Comment: As you can see in the documentation this method is "deprecated" which means "outdated" and in case of an experimental API may easily mean "already removed". Try the sibling method DOMSnapshot.captureSnapshot in Chrome Canary or in a [Chromium trunk build](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/).

Comment: @wOxxOm - I tried again with `DOMSnapshot.captureSnapshot` and it working. Thanks for the help. Strangely now `DOMSnapshot.getSnapshot` is also working now. Not sure what changed.